# How does SelectionIdBuilder work?

Tags: powerbi

I'm trying to understand how the SelectionIdBuilder works. I'm especially trying to understand when and how to use `.withMeasure` and `.withSeries`. The information in GitHub [(here)](https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-visuals/blob/master/Visual/Selection.md#creating-selection-ids-selectionidbuilder) didn't enlighten me. I can't find any real examples of code using either `.withMeasure` or `.withSeries`.

I got my visual to work, using only `.withCategory`, based on other visuals I saw, but I want to *really* understand the SelectionIdBuilder.

I'd sure appreciate an education regarding how SelectionIdBuilder works and where I might find more detailed info about it.